# Can I use POLL to determine when USB disconnected

Tags: linux, udev, devices

I'm working on an old Linux 2.4 kernel and I'm trying to figure out how I can send a signal from the device driver to the application when the USB device has been disconnected.

I've been reading my way through the Linux Device Drivers 2nd Edition, but I haven't found anything relevant.

Currently, my application is using `select` to determine if the file descriptor has read or write data available.

I'm wondering if the POLL feature of `devfs` from this era would provide a reliable way to detect if the device has disconnected.

If not, is there a best practice for making the device disconnection notify an application?

Comment: you could also use inotify on /dev or a subdirectory if it, but that might breally noisy and need filtering.  If you had the device or a fd related to teh device open, you could probably poll the fd and get an error when it disconnected (or a zero size read or something).

Comment: I haven't heard of inotify before, I'm going to read about that and see if that might suit the purpose I need.  I don't have the file open but I think I can hack that in, that could work.